# WebAPI 2 custom routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, routes

I have added the custome routing to a WebAPI ASP.NET application, using framework 4.7.1, by adding the attribute on top of the method:

```
public class ShapeFileAnalysisController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetDataValues")]
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetDataValues()
    {
        string result = Models.ShapeFileReader.GetAdmin2();
        HttpResponseMessage response = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new StringContent(result, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        return response;
    }  
}
```

but when I add [Route("...")} attribute the full URL changes from mysite.com/api/ShapeFileAnalysis to mysite.com/GetDataValues

the webapiconfig.cs is:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        config.EnableCors();

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

What I should do to have still mysite.com/api/ShapeFileAnalysis/GetDataValues ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attribute routing uses the route template placed in the attribute.

Your route has only `GetDataValues` so that will become the full route path.

```
mysite.com/GetDataValues
```

If you place the desired route path

```
//GET api/ShapeFileAnalysis/GetDataValues
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/ShapeFileAnalysis/GetDataValues")]
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetDataValues() {
    //...
}
```

Then you will get the desired path

```
mysite.com/api/ShapeFileAnalysis/GetDataValues
```

You can set a common prefix for an entire controller by using the [`[RoutePrefix]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#route-prefixes) attribute

```
[RoutePrefix( "api/ShapeFileAnalysis" )] 
public class ShapeFileAnalysisController : ApiController {

    //GET api/ShapeFileAnalysis/GetDataValues
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetDataValues")]
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetDataValues() {
        //...omitted for brevity
    }  
}
```

Reference [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Answer (score 0):

It's posible that you are mixing two ways to implement a WebApi in Net framework as is mention on the Microsoft Documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection.

In the first one (the one that you are follow) the routing matching is throught the parameter of the verbs (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE), this means that when you do a Get you distinguish between method using the parameter's name (examples are aviable in Microsoft's Documentation mentioned before).

In the second one you can Add a Route and controller route on the top to tell the compiler in which route it should to expose the method.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have the time to test in VS my suggestion but I believe that you need to add one more attribute - [RoutePrefixAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn202110(v%3Dvs.118)).
Your code should be be following:

```
[RoutePrefix( "api/ShapeFileAnalysis" )]    //  new line of code!
public class ShapeFileAnalysisController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetDataValues")]
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetDataValues()
    {

    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this situation "mysite.com/api/ShapeFileAnalysis/GetDataValues"
If all requests will be in this template. **You don't have to use Custom Route**.

The other answer is the solution of the problem, but I want to offer a different alternative. **Change default route** and **remove all route attributes**.
Route Template add action tag.

Example:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        config.EnableCors();

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Referance: [Routing in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api)